# How to change order of data given in Array based on order key given in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that I get from API. I need to sort the data based on `Order` value.
the data is kind of complex, here is an example:

```
const data = [{
  gallery: {
    id: 91,
    media: [
      {
        type: 'image',
        file: 'http://xxxxx.jpg', 
      },
    ],
    title: 'title 3',
    description:
      'test',
    order: 3,
    is_main: false,
    created_at: '2020-08-02T15:19:44.319133Z',
    updated_at: '2020-08-02T16:48:06.766478Z',
  }
},
{
  gallery: {
    id: 91,
    media: [
      {
        type: 'image',
        file: 'http://xxxxx.jpg', 
      },
    ],
    title: 'title 2',
    description:
      'test',
    order: 2,
    is_main: false,
    created_at: '2020-08-02T15:19:44.319133Z',
    updated_at: '2020-08-02T16:48:06.766478Z',
  }
},]
```

I need a way to sort the data based on ORDER given in api.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use array.reduce to do a simple insertion sort.

```js
let sorted = data.reduce((acc, next) => {
  acc[next.gallery.order] = next;
  return acc;
},[]);
```

If you have the need to avoid any empty indexes, you can filter undefined after the sort.

```js
let sorted = data
  .reduce((acc, next) => {
    acc[next.gallery.order] = next;
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .filter((el) => el);
```

Comment: I am happy to help!